# Cannot input text in field with puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I am trying to automate the typing in a field using puppeteer. I have attached the element that shows up when i inspect. Below is the code i have tried but it doesn't work (nothing fills in). Can someone help?

`await page.$eval('.notranslate.public-DraftEditor-content', e => e.value = "jubaitca")`

[element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nKMX.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell me if these codes below doesn't worked.
Try this instead:

```
await page.type('.notranslate.public-DraftEditor-content', 'jubaitca', {delay: 10})
```

`page.keyboard` version:

```
await page.focus('.notranslate.public-DraftEditor-content')
await page.keyboard.type('jubaitca')
```

or, alternatively:

```
await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.notranslate.public-DraftEditor-content').value = 'jubaitca')
```

Comment: the first one works and im sure the second one will but the alternative does not work...is there anyway to get it to work without typing?

Comment: Typing is just changing the value, it's basically just the same as the third code. DRY, develop faster.
 
If you want the code run faster, don't add `slowMo` option in the `puppeteer.launch` or make the delay less than before.

Comment: I've edited the first code, you can change the delay number inside the options

Comment: My pleasure, and i would be thankful if you please select my answer as correct answer if you get the code to be worked and running perfectly.